# How to convert Nov 18 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time) to (yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss) format in javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, datetime

I'm working with full calendar css package. When I select date from database I get output like this.

 **Nov 18 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)** 

I want to change my date to this **(YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-ss)** format.
I suft net but I didn't find a way to convert whole format.

Thats why I'm repeating the question.
Please help me.
Thank you.

```
  function convert(str) {
       var date = new Date(str),
       mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
       day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2),
       hour=("0"+date.getHours()).slice(-2),
       min=("0"+date.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
       sec=("0"+date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
       return [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day, hour, min, sec].join("-");
  }

   var d = new Date(calEvent.start);
   var sdate_1=convert(d);
```

THis is the output I'm getting after format.
**2015-11-18-12-00-00**

My real output is **2015-11-18 06:30:00.0**

Comment: **`Microsoft SQL Server` or `MySQL` or both?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same requirement today, to format a **Javascript Date** into a **MYSQL datetime**, but at the javascript end.

Here's a solution.

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

or in your case;

```
new Date(calEvent.start).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `DATE_FORMAT()` in MySQL.The DATE_FORMAT() function is used to display date/time data in different formats.

Something like DATE_FORMAT(date,format)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date_column_name`,%m-%d-%Y-%H-%i-%S) 
FROM
table_name
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly I can't change the sql query. I have to prase the javascript output

Comment: Can please give me an example.